# Iterate on SQL group by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have the following models with associations:

```
House belongs_to User
User has_many House
```

Is there a way that I can do something like using SQL (not ruby group_by)

```
House.group(:user).each |houses_grouped_by_user|
  #Each of these objects would be a set of houses with the same user id
end
```

Comment: why you are not using `user.houses`?? and loop through `User.includes(:houses)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching).

As your commenter suggested, based on the associations in your model setup, you should lean on the functionality that the associations provide you!

Thus:

```
user.houses.each do |user_houses|  
# do whatever you want to the user_houses  
end
```

If you want to iterate through the `houses` in larger groups, you can use other iterative methods -- but start with the association and go from there.